# Wikipedia PHP - handle results

Tags: php, api, mediawiki

I use the MediaWiki api to get Wikipedia a PHP serialized arrray of information about a specific country.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Belgium&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=php
```

**My question**

How do I get a specific field out of this array? Like f.e.:

- Capital
- Population census
- Map caption (region, official languages, ...)

I'm not familiar with this output...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The api is not meant to access properties like `capital` for `belgium` or something like that. You will just get the wikipage as `wiki` source code together with some extra information like page title. A wiki page can for example contain information about a programming language, a flower, a car or a country in your example, it is just markdown no special data fields.

The response format is serialized php data. Use `unserialize` to parse it into an array but don't expect to get structured information about `belgium`:

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Belgium&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=php');
$data = unserialize($response);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Ok thanks, all the answers were clear to me. This one answers my question well! I will use php functions to explode this content into usable arrays.

Comment: Ok, happy scraping :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like serialized PHP and you can [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) it as others have answered. I'd suggest using the [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/) format instead:

> `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Belgium&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=`json

You can then use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to get parse the JSON response and transform it into an associative array:

```
$json = file_get_contents($file);
$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);

foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
    // get the details you need
}
```

Comment: I guess using unserialize together with the "php" format will be faster. No need for json here

Answer (score 0):

Use this function `unserialize()`:

```
$array = file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Belgium&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&format=json');
$array = unserialize( $array );
print_r( $array );
```

Comment: Yes this was clear to me, but the content that start with | leader_title1 = [[Monarchy of Belgium|King]]
| leader_name1 = [[Philippe of Belgium|King Philippe]]
| leader_title2 = [[Prime Minister of Belgium|Prime Minister]]
| leader_name2 = [[Elio Di Rupo]]
| legislature = [[Belgian Federal Parliament|Federal Parliament]]
| upper_house = [[Senate (Belgium)|Senate]]